# Tag merger request: moving and relocation

Tags: support, tags

Please merge the tags:

- [relocation](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relocation)
- [moving](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moving)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moving tag was moved to relocation